# SQL filling missing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what I guess is a common data warehouse problem.

What I have been trying to do is to make an SQL Query that has no gaps between dates.

The fact table only registers records that are measured and recorded into the table. This case is about registered oil production on vessels at sea. Some days there is no productions on some of the ships.

So here is my simple data warehouse: `DimVessel`, `DimDate` and `FactProduction`. And below you see the final resultset I want.

I want the SQL Query to fill the fact table with `vesselkey` and `Production` even if there is no production on the vessel. Remember there can be production on a few vessels some days and all vessels on other days (best case).

I hope somebody can help me out here.

**DimVessel**

```
VesselKey| VesselName
1        | Vessel 1
2        | Vessel 2
3        | Vessel 3
4        | Vessel 4
5        | Vessel 5
```

**DimDate**

```
DateKey     |Date
20160517    |2016-05-17 00:00:00.000
20160518    |2016-05-18 00:00:00.000
20160519    |2016-05-19 00:00:00.000
20160520    |2016-05-20 00:00:00.000
```

**FactProduction**

```
DateKey     |VesselKey  |Production
20160517    |4          |12505
20160517    |5          |1276
20160517    |3          |88
20160517    |2          |3919
20160518    |4          |8785
20160518    |5          |736
20160518    |1          |3754
20160518    |2          |5654
20160519    |2          |1654
20160520    |1          |2016
20160520    |3          |6059
20160520    |4          |10980
20160520    |5          |663
```

This is what I want, the final result set:

```
DateKey     |VesselKey  |Production
20160517    |4          |12505
20160517    |5          |1276
20160517    |3          |88
20160517    |2          |3919
20160517    |1          |0
20160518    |4          |8785
20160518    |5          |736
20160518    |3          |0
20160518    |1          |3754
20160518    |2          |5654
20160519    |2          |1654
20160519    |1          |0
20160519    |3          |0
20160519    |4          |0
20160519    |5          |0
20160520    |1          |2016
20160520    |3          |6059
20160520    |2          |4059
20160520    |4          |10980
20160520    |5          |663
```

Comment: Someone will help you for sure. If you format your question to be readable by a human being, if you show us what you have done so far and if you tell us what exactly is your problem

Comment: Are you familiar with left joins?

Comment: I made some corrections to the grammar of your question; if they have changed the meaning in any way, please feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: Hello again. Sorry if my grammar is not too good. I am familiar With left joins and I tried this solution that is quite like the one below.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store data that does not exist? I'm not a fan of storing fact data that does not physically exist in a source system.

You can achieve the result you want with the query below (not tested)

```
SELECT DD.DateKey
,DV.VesselKey
,Production = ISNULL(FP.Production)
FROM DimDate DD
    INNER JOIN DimVessel DV ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN FactProduction FP ON (FP.DateKey = DD.DateKey AND FP.VesselKey = DV.VesselKey)
WHERE DD.DateKey BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

If you insist on wanting to store the data then you simply need to add a join to your source data instead of the FactProduction table and then insert the results into your fact

Comment: Regarding data that doesn't exist, are you referring to the dimDate table?

Comment: No pretty sure I said fact data. DimDate is a dimension. If we want to go into semantics then DimDate is sourced from a calendar (Pseudo). IMO a record missing from a fact table is more informative than creating one to fill gaps. Could indicate source data issue or merely highlight that data has not come through/come through yet

Comment: Hi and thanks for all comments. Sometimes like here when Production is Down, no data is registered. In a time line 0 Production is also data, even if it is not measured in any way. When presented in a chart or graph, you get a hole in Your data. May be that is understandable, but it also can be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
select  allCombinations.DateKey,
        allCombinations.VesselKey,
        isnull(p.Production, 0) as Production
from    (
         select d.DateKey,
                v.VesselKey
         from   @Dates as d
         cross join @Vessels as v
        ) as allCombinations
left join @Production as p
on      allCombinations.DateKey = p.DateKey
        and allCombinations.VesselKey = p.VesselKey
```

The full code in order to verify this solution is the following:

```
declare @Vessels table
    (
     VesselKey int primary key
                   not null,
     VesselName as (N'Vessel ' + cast(VesselKey as nvarchar))
    )

insert  into @Vessels
        (VesselKey)
values  (1),
        (2),
        (3),
        (4),
        (5)

select  *
from    @Vessels as v

declare @Dates table
    (
     DateKey int primary key
                 not null,
     Date as (try_convert(datetime2, cast(DateKey as nvarchar)
              + ' 00:00:00.000'))
    )

insert  into @Dates
        (DateKey)
values  (20160517),
        (20160518),
        (20160519),
        (20160520)

select  *
from    @Dates as d

declare @Production table
    (
     DateKey int,
     VesselKey int,
     Production int
    )

insert  into @Production
        (DateKey, VesselKey, Production)
values  (20160517, 4, 12505),
        (20160517, 5, 1276),
        (20160517, 3, 88),
        (20160517, 2, 3919),
        (20160518, 4, 8785),
        (20160518, 5, 736),
        (20160518, 1, 3754),
        (20160518, 2, 5654),
        (20160519, 2, 1654),
        (20160520, 1, 2016),
        (20160520, 3, 6059),
        (20160520, 4, 10980),
        (20160520, 5, 663)

select  *
from    @Production as p



select  allCombinations.DateKey,
        allCombinations.VesselKey,
        isnull(p.Production, 0) as Production
from    (
         select d.DateKey,
                v.VesselKey
         from   @Dates as d
         cross join @Vessels as v
        ) as allCombinations
left join @Production as p
on      allCombinations.DateKey = p.DateKey
        and allCombinations.VesselKey = p.VesselKey
```

Let me know if the result is not the one you were looking for.

Comment: Yes and thank you. And I guess in a second Query where I want a more detailed data by hour, I can use this Query just adding a TimeKey (0-1439) from DimTime With register a Production sample every minute during the day. This second Query will be a sliding window showing the last 24 hours like 10:16 am yesterday to 10:15 am today and 5 minutes later 10:21 am yesterday to 10:20 today. I will try using this Query on my new case too. And thanks again for very fast responding. regards Geir