# sql pivot and combine two queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pivot

I have the following query in a Stored Procedure that pulls up store info and quantity for a supplied product code:

```
select l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code as store, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone,  b.store_code, b.prod_code,  b.prod_id,  
sum(convert(int, b.bin_qty_stocks)) as inv
,  dbo.bb_fnGHBQt(c.Channel_Index - 1, b.prod_id) as web_hb
,  case when b.store_code = '0030' then sum(convert(int, bin_qty_stocks))  - dbo.bb_fnGHBQt(c.Channel_Index - 1, prod_id) 
    else sum(convert(int, b.bin_qty_stocks))  end as inv_avail
from store s (nolock)
    inner join province p
        on p.province_id = s.province_id
    inner join bb_vStoreLevels l (nolock) 
        on l.store_code_id = s.store_Code_id
    left join bb_bin b (nolock)
        on b.store_code_id = s.store_code_id
        and b.B_Code in ('ST', 'BC', 'R') 
        and b.prod_code = @inSKU
    cross join bb_B2B_Channel c (nolock)            
where (((l.region is not null) and (l.region <> '077')) or (l.store = '0030'))
    and s.store_code <> '0055'
    and (l.date_opened <= getdate())
    and ((l.date_closed is null) or (l.date_closed > getdate()))    
    and c.channel_description = 'WWW'   
GROUP BY l.region, l.region_description, s.store_code, s.name, s.city, p.province_code, s.telephone
, b.store_code, b.prod_code, b.prod_id, c.Channel_Index
```

Then I have another Stored Procedure that horizontally lists up to 6 siblings of a given SKU :

```
;WITH X AS 
   (
    SELECT prod_code, Parent_Sku, Parent_Child_Priority, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent_Sku ORDER BY Parent_Child_Priority DESC) rn 
    FROM bb_Product 
    WHERE
        Parent_SKU in (SELECT Parent_SKU
                        FROM bb_Product
                        WHERE prod_code = @inSKU)
        and ParentFlag <> 'P'
        and prod_code <> @inSKU
    ),
Y AS (
      SELECT * , 'Sib' + ISNULL(NULLIF(Cast(rn AS Varchar(10)), '0'),'') Sibs
      FROM X
      WHERE rn < 7 
)
 SELECT Sib1,Sib2,Sib3,Sib4,Sib5,Sib6
 FROM 
    (
    SELECT Parent_Sku , Sibs , prod_code
    FROM Y
    ) a
     PIVOT (MAX(prod_code)
            FOR Sibs
            IN (Sib,Sib1,Sib2,Sib3,Sib4,Sib5,Sib6))p
```

What I'm trying to do is combine these two queries in a single Stored Procedure so I can list sibling (inv) quantities along with the original item quantity. It would look something like this below:

```
region  region_description  store   name    city    province_code   telephone   store_code  product_code    product_id  inv web_hb  inv_avail   sib1    sib2    sib3    sib4    sib5    sib6

001         001-CO          0042    XYZ Colorado Springs    CO        123-123-1234  0042    1234566         123456784   1   0           1       1       0       1       4       1       2
```

I haven't done anything like this before so would appreciate some input and direction to achieve the desired output.
Thanks and much appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the output of the two individual procedures?

Comment: Could you please provide us with an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or some sample data in tempTables / tableVariables as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530075/sql-filling-missing-dates/37532218#37532218

Comment: Tab Alleman, The output of the first SP is what I put in at the very end of my original post (minus the last 6 columns). The output of the second SP is just lists sib1, sib2.....sib6 and below it lists up to 6 product_codes.

Comment: Ralph, I wanted to provide some sample data but there are quite a few tables and thought it would be time consuming to create those with usable data on SQL Fiddle. What do you guys think of this idea: create a function to return quantity of a given product_code, then add sib1-sib6 SKU's as columns headers and values would be the function returns?

Comment: you should make your sib query a function and just APPLY it to each row