# two counts in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I want to find for each store the number of products for that store/number of customers of that store

```
Customer                 
Id | dealerId           
 1 | 10             
 2 | 11             
 3 | 10                     

Product             
Id   | CustomerId           
100  |  1               
200  |  3   
300  |  2       

store
Id
10
11
```

The result for the above example would be:

```
StoreId | value

10      |  2/2
11      |  1/1
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or some sample data in tableVariables as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530075/sql-filling-missing-dates/37532218#37532218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.dealerID as Store, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.ID) as NumOfCustomers,
  COUNT(p.ID) as NumOfProducts
FROM 
  Customers C
  INNER JOIN
  Products p on p.CustomerId = c.Id
GROUP BY
  c.dealerID
```

Comment: I think you'll probably want a `count(distinct ...)` on the customer count even though the sample data doesn't make it clear whether that can actually happen.

Comment: Fair enough @shawnt00 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select S.Id AS StoreId, COUNT(p.Id) AS ProductId, COUNT(CAST.Id) AS CustomerId
from Store S 
    left join Customer C on C.dealerId = Scheduler.StoreId
    left join Product P on P.CustomerId = CAST.Id
group by S.Id
```